# Dynamic dictionary entry tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a basic GUI in tkinter but I want it to be dynamic.
The end goal is to have a nested dictionary populated by this GUI and that the user can add as many items as he/she want. 
I managed to enter a full *single* dictionary with some simple (and pretty repetetive) code:

for example:
Edit

```
from Tkinter import *

top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)

top.mainloop()
```

Now im looking for a way for the GUI to have a button (like a + sign) that will allow the user to open another single or a set of entries each time he/she presses the button and populate the dictionary accordingly.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. The code above is nothing but a small, somewhat related section of a larger code, and is not standalone, nor is it the only isolated part of the issue.

Comment: Edited to have a simple, runnable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to have a Label & Entry object. You can collect these objects in a collection type such as `list` or `dict`.

The example below does that using a `list`:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class LabelEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, text="User Name", *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self._label = tk.Label(self, text=text)
        self._entry = tk.Entry(self, bd=5)
        self._label.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        self._entry.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)


def add_a_le(master, widgets_list):
    widgets_list.append(LabelEntry(master))
    widgets_list[-1].pack()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_label_entries = list()
    add_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Add")
    add_btn['command'] = lambda m=root, ws=my_label_entries: add_a_le(m, ws)
    add_btn.pack(side='bottom')
    tk.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ok, one more thing, how do I go about getting the values from these entries (assuming I need to know from which field they came from of course)?

Comment: @Rafi `my_label_entries[2].get()` returns the value of the 3rd entry as a string _at the time when it was called_.